# How to set url case sensitivity in java?

Tags: java, api, http, tomcat

I hava a java API that is accessed as:

```
www.mydomain.com/Abc/xyz
```

I would like to allow access to it just on upper case for the "Abc" part of the url.

So, access should be allowed only for:

```
www.mydomain.com/ABC/xyz
```

Where in java or tomcat that is configured?

When executing it through Eclipse it is indeed accessing at the upper case version (ABC) as it should.

But when the API is deployed as a .war for some reason it changes the access to "Abc" while "ABC" doesn't work anymore. Not sure why.

Thanks.

Comment: Check whether your WAR file is called `Abc.war` or `ABC.war`.

Comment: Yes. That was it! You can add as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you.